# Using a variable called 'request' in dictionary with Python Cheetah3

Tags: python, cheetah

I've been experimenting with Cheetah3 as a templating engine to transform XML into something else. I have this working, using the below example XML input

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example code="HI">
    <codes>
        <code>1</code>
        <code>2</code>
    </codes>
</example>
```

and the following code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import xmltodict
from Cheetah.Template import Template


with open('example.xml', 'r') as f:
    example_xml = f.read()
example_dict = xmltodict.parse(example_xml)

templateDefinition = "This is a template.\n" \
                     "Example: $example\n" \
                     "Example: $example.codes\n" \
                     "Example: $example.codes.code[0]"
template = Template(templateDefinition, searchList=[example_dict])
print(str(template))
```

Now if I change the input XML to be contained with a `<request>` root element (instead of `<example>`), and the template code from `$example` to `$request` it breaks. It would appear that `$request` is a reserved word in Cheetah3. Is there anyway around that, short of changing the root XML element before using Cheetah3?

Comment: Can you describe "it breaks" in a little more detail?  For example, do you get an error message and if so, what is it?

Comment: (Cheetah maintainer is here.) `$request` returns `None`. Strange. I'm investigating…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` is a special variable in Cheetah3, lets just try to rename the variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import xmltodict
from Cheetah.Template import Template


with open('example.xml', 'r') as f:
    example_xml = f.read()
example_dict = xmltodict.parse(example_xml)

# Rename 'request' to '_request' or any other name that is not reserved
if 'request' in example_dict:
    example_dict['_request'] = example_dict.pop('request')

templateDefinition = "This is a template.\n" \
                     "Example: $_request\n" \
                     "Example: $_request.codes\n" \
                     "Example: $_request.codes.code[0]"
template = Template(templateDefinition, searchList=[example_dict])
print(str(template))
```

Answer (score 1):

(Cheetah maintainer is here.)

Class [`Template`](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/blob/49485225ada5ca3bfad143c3c2b25d677fa316a4/Cheetah/Template.py#L186) has a base class [`Servlet`](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/blob/49485225ada5ca3bfad143c3c2b25d677fa316a4/Cheetah/Servlet.py#L9) that declares [a few class-level names](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/blob/master/Cheetah/Servlet.py#L14-L17) that become reserved attributes.

For your current code the solution is to remove the offending attribute:

```py
from Cheetah.Servlet import Servlet
del Servlet.request
```

The real solution would be to allow `searchList` to override class attributes or to divorce `Servlet` and `Template` (or to remove `Servlet` completely — it was created for [Webware](https://pypi.org/project/Webware/) which was abandoned long ago). Both would be breaking changes and require a new major release.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to do for this as I don't need this module, however I've marked the other as the official answer as this solution may not work for everyone. I appreciate your answer though.